# Modify the week in a Calendar

Tags: java, calendar

Hello i'm using a `Calendar` in Java

What I want is to change my Calendar value, and have the following / previous week.

I tried

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.DATE-7);
```

But it acts weird

Comment: What does "acts weird" means?

Comment: It gives me bad date, for exemple if I act 7, sometimes it gives less one month or things like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried (copied/pasted from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29)):

```
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use something like the following instead:

`c.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);`

Your code is completely wrong. 
`cal.DATE-7` does not mean "7 days before today". `Calendar.DATE` is just a constant that specifies the field type for `Calendar`.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Next week.

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
         .plusWeeks( 1L )
```

Last week.

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
         .minusWeeks( 1L )
```

## Using java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy classes such as `Calendar` & `Date`.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

## Add/subtract weeks

Adding or subtracting weeks with a `LocalDate` is easy. Call the [`plusWeeks`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusWeeks-long-) or [`minusWeeks`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#minusWeeks-long-) methods.

```
LocalDate nextWeek = today.plusWeeks( 1L );
LocalDate lastWeek = today.minusWeeks( 1L );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)-1);
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
}
```

Hope this helped, have Fun!